# Why isn't the loop working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-selectors

There is a string as follows "100200300400500".
I am trying to split it into subsets of 3 like "100" "200" "300" "400" "500".
I want them as mouseover title/tooltip of child elements in sequence.
That is the when you hover over the first child the tooltip should say 100, and when you hover over over the second child the tooltip should say 200 and so on.
Here result = 100200300400500
and str = sub strings of length 3 of result string

Below is what I have achieved so far. But the tooltips on all the child divs read 100.
What am I doing wrong?

```
       $.ajax({
       url: "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/47127613/ajax.txt",
       dataType: "text",
       success: function(result) {
           var str = result;
           if (str.length > 3) str = str.substring(0, 3); {
               for (var n = 1; n < 100; n++) {
                   $("#parent:nth-child(n)").children().attr('title', str + ' Installs');
                   for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
                       str(i) = str(i + 3);
                   }
               }
           }
       }
   });
```

HTML

```
    <div id="parent">
    <div class="child1"></div>
    <div class="child2"></div>
    <div class="child3"></div>
    <div class="child4"></div>
    <div class="child5"></div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Could you post the HTML structure as well?

Comment: There are lots of bug in your code.

Comment: @aokaddaoc Can you point them out please?

Comment: Why do you want to split a string to do this? If the labels are really 100, 200 etc. you could make them in a loop. If they are more complicated you could store them in an array.

Answer (score 1):

You could try splitting using this snippet. Is that what you need?

```js
var r = [], str = "100200300400500"; 
// you may want to check for appropriate str.length
// if (str.length % 3 != 0) { ... }
str.split('')
   .map(function (v, i, arr) {
         void(i && (i % 3 == 0 || i == arr.length-1)
               ? this.push(
                   i == arr.length -1  ? arr.slice(-3) 
                                       : arr.slice(i-3, i)) 
               : null); 
         return v;
        }, r);
document.querySelector('#result').innerHTML = 
   r.map( function (v) {return v.join('')}).join('<br>');
```

```html
<div id="result"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The value of `n` isn't being interpreted as its in a string. Your selector should look something like: `$("#parent:nth-child(" + n + ")")`

Answer (score 0):

You should loop through the `div` elements and assign the `title` attribute.

```js
var str = '100200300400500';
// Initialize the counter
var c = 0;
// Loop through all 'div's that are direct child of '#parent'
$('#parent > div').each(function() {
  // Assign the 'title' attribute to the current 'div'($(this)).
  // The 'str.substring(c, c + 3)' will extract a sub string from
  // the current index(c) till 3 more indexes(c + 3).
  $(this).attr('title', str.substring(c, c + 3) + ' Installs');
  // Increment the counter by 3.
  c += 3;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="parent">
  <div class="child1">One</div>
  <div class="child2">Two</div>
  <div class="child3">Three</div>
  <div class="child4">Four</div>
  <div class="child5">Five</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I've tried both the selectors but still all the tooltips are showing the first 3 letters of string.

Comment: Care to explain what's not helpful, so that I can improve?

Comment: Hey! This kind of works but not for every child div but leaving one gap.

Comment: @AnupamRam - Well, if your HTML structure is same, it should work like it does here.

Comment: Hmm, let me have a look at my HTML.

Comment: Can you please explain what's going on in this code of yours?

Comment: @AnupamRam - I've added an explanation.

Answer (score -1):

To access Array cell you should write:

```
str[i]; //not str(i)
```